# Can't find appsettings.json in my WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

So I'm making a WPF application in the new .net core 3.0 framework! And I'm trying to add connectionstring into the appsettings.json. But the thing is I can't find appsettings.json in my project. How do I fix this?! Is appsettings.json added automatically or do I have to make it myself!?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it manually. A small how-to can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings).

Essentially your appsettings.json would look like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23713024)

Comment: Thanks @Rob. Added the important part.